# How to download full-size images from google shared album

Tags: python, google-photos

I am trying to download original full size images from a shared Album (shared for everyone) of Google Photo with python.
I get album with commands:

```
url=sys.argv[1]
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
dong = response.read()
dong=dong.split("\n")
for i in range(len(dong)-1,-1,-1):
    if len(dong[i])>277 or len(dong[i])<275 or dong[i][0:3]!=',["' :
        del dong[i]
hinh=[]
for i,d in enumerate(dong):
    hinh.append(d[3:47])   
for h in hinh:
    href=url.replace("?key","/photo/"+h+"?key")
    print href
```

Then I parse and get link for images, but all are in size 478x638.

Comment: Are you using the paid or free Google Photos? The free one doesn't store the full-size images, IIRC.

Comment: No. I use free version. But it does store full-size images. Everyone with the link may downloads full-size images from web browser (click on three dot button on top-right screen, then choose download all)

Comment: Try to find the difference `URL` for the high-res Images.

Comment: There is only one url for shared album, for ex. https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMQSEnTIx5Jz_hTFYecLtfQz70SarFTc6Pd-w-VvX0qbJRvjoDjBcPiD0ZZATmjfw?key=N0ZtQVFKbFNaZDZXeDVlRlc0S1hqMUd0OF85alF3